# Date internationalization in JavaScript with ICU formats

Tags: javascript, date, localization, internationalization

Using the [Intl extension](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) in PHP, I can do custom date formats like this:

```
$fmt = new \IntlDateFormatter('fr-CA', null, null, null, \IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, 'EEE d MMM yyyy à HH:mm');
echo $fmt->format(new \DateTime());
```

What is important is that I can pass in any string composed of characters from the [ICU Date Field Symbol Table](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Field-Symbol-Table).

I already use Moment.js in my project but it [doesn't seem like they are interested in working on ICU compatibility](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2050) (even for version 3). As a last resort I can duplicate my formats file to include both ICU and Moment.js symbols for each format but ideally I'd like to avoid that.

I looked into the [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) object of the ECMAScript Internationalization API and it doesn't seem to have such functionality so what options do I have in JavaScript?